# How to translate"If $X$ then $Y$ unless $Z$" to propositional logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, logic-translation

As the title says, the given sentence is

> If $x$ then $y$ unless $z$"

Now according to my learning "If $x$ then $y$" translates to: $x\rightarrow y$.
Also according to Kenneth Rosen's book (second paragraph on [this](https://goo.gl/9QMrUv) page) "$y$ unless $z$" translates to $z\rightarrow y$. Now we have to AND (conjunction) these two. According to 7th formula in table 7 [here](https://goo.gl/urFzVG), this is done as follows:

$(x \rightarrow y)\land (z\rightarrow y) \equiv (x\lor z)\rightarrow y$

However the solution given in the book (not the Kenneth Rosen's book) is

> $(x\land \lnot z)\rightarrow y$

Though above seems to be direct verbal translation of the statement "It $x$ then $y$ unless $z$", I am confused how following the rules as given in the book which also sounds correct yields different result.

Comment: If you get home, then you can eat the last piece of cake. Unless I got there first. Namely, if you get home and I haven't, then you can eat the last piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Rosen ([7th ed, page 6](http://www.slideshare.net/Raj039/discrete-mathematics-and-its-applications-7th-edition-by-rosen)), “$q$ unless $¬p$” translates : “if $p$, then $q$”.

Thus, for :

> "if $x$ then $y$ unless $z$"

assuming a comma : "if $x$ then $y$, unless $z$", we have :

> “if $¬z$, then if $x$ then $y$".

Now for the symbols :

> $¬z \to (x \to y)$

is equivalent to : $(\lnot z \land x) \to y$ by [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)), i.e. the *tautology* :

> $((P \land Q) \to R) \Leftrightarrow (P \to (Q \to R))$.

Comment: billion thanks...want to ask something off topic: which is the best book on logic?

Comment: @PardonMeForMySuperPoorMaths - there are many ... e.g. Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=bX91C6GOBkcC&printsec=frontcover) (2003).

Answer (score 1):

> If $x$ then $y$ unless $z$.

The word *unless* in the original sentence refers to the *if* at the beginning, that is, **the implication** (*if*) **holds** every time you **do not** have $z$.

> $y$ unless $z$.

In the second sentence, on the other hand, the word *unless* refers to the $y$ at the beginning, that is, **$y$ holds** every time you **do not** have $z$.

Comment: damn, is it something like $\lnot z \rightarrow (x\rightarrow y)\equiv (\lnot z \land x) \rightarrow y$

Comment: Am just guessing how Rosen's approach or some mathematical logic will apply to "If $x$ then $y$ unless $z$" to make it more verbose. The book gives direct answer thinking it should be intuitive.

Comment: Does ***the implication (if) holds every time you do not have $z$*** translates to $(x\rightarrow y)\rightarrow \lnot z$ and hence $(\lnot z \land x)\rightarrow y$

Comment: Ok after little more thinking I came to conclusion that it is $z \rightarrow (x\rightarrow y)$. Am I correct. If yes is it equivalent to $(z \land x)\rightarrow y$?